# scalaFX standalone execute jar file

Tags: jar, sbt, scalafx

Good day! Help me, please. I startup this example

```
sbt> run
```

It's okey all play, after

```
sbt> package
```

Will build jar file, after double click messge:

`Error: A JNI error has occured, please check your installation and try again.`

Scala version: 2.12.4. JVM:1.8.0_152. ScalaFX:8.0.102-R11

hello.scala: `

```
package hello

import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.paint.Color._
import scalafx.scene.shape.Rectangle

object HelloStage extends JFXApp {

  stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title.value = "Hello Stage"
    width = 600
    height = 450
    scene = new Scene {
      fill = LightGreen
      content = new Rectangle {
        x = 25
        y = 40
        width = 100
        height = 100
        fill <== when(hover) choose Green otherwise Red
      }
    }
  }
}
```

build.sbt:

```
name := "Scala"

organization := "scalafx.org"

version := "1.0.5"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-Xcheckinit", "-encoding", "utf8")

resourceDirectory in Compile := (scalaSource in Compile).value

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "8.0.102-R11",)

addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)

fork := true
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a *Java* `classpath` issue. When you try to execute the resulting *JAR* file, it cannot find the jar files that it needs to run.

Try the following:

Firstly, copy & paste the following to `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")
```

This loads the `sbt-assembly` plugin, which will create a *fat JAR* file, containing all of the dependencies.

Secondly, change your `build.sbt` file to the following:

```
name := "Scala"

organization := "scalafx.org"

version := "1.0.5"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-Xcheckinit", "-encoding", "utf8")

libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "8.0.102-R11"

fork := true

mainClass in assembly := Some("hello.HelloStage")
```

This simplifies what you originally had. The *macro paradise* compiler plugin is not required, and I also removed the slightly odd `resourceDirectory` setting.

To create the *fat JAR*, run the command:

```
sbt
sbt> assembly
```

The JAR file you're looking for is most likely located at `target/scala-2.12/Scala-assembly-1.0.5.jar`. You should now be good to go...

Alternatively, you can [add all the necessary *JAR* files to your classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html). Another plugin that can help with that (you probably shouldn't use it with `sbt-assembly`) - is [`sbt-native-packager`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager), which creates installers for you. You can then install your app and run it like a regular application.